# Can I use gapi.hangout.onair namespace for regular, non-live/non-aired google hangouts app?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

Creating a simple speech and presentation app in google hangouts.

I want to use `gapi.hangout.onair` functions without having a live broadcast. I'm trying to assign a "speaker" role to  a participant, and if I can I'd like to use `setDisplayedParticipantInBroadcast(id)` for assigning the "speaker" (among other functions).

Will I be able to implement this if the app is meant for a regular hangout session? If not, is there a hack/workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation at https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.onair#gapi.hangout.onair.setDisplayedParticipantInBroadcast states that the call will fail if the Hangout is not On Air. Which makes sense - what this function does is set who will be displayed during the *recording*; it does not change who is displayed to *other members* of the hangout.

If you would like to set who is displayed for another participant, you need that person to run a Hangout app that calls either [setDisplayedParticipant](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.layout#gapi.hangout.layout.DefaultVideoFeed-methods) or [createParticipantVideoFeed](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.layout#gapi.hangout.layout.createParticipantVideoFeed) to switch to the person you designate as "speaker" - you should try both to see which works best for your needs, but understand that the person watching can change this if they wish. You can set who the "speaker" is using the shared state methods in [gapi.hangout.data](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data).